# FFMPEG h264_videotoolbox output is strange

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, video-toolbox

I want to use h264_videotoolbox codec to encode my video in FFMPEG lib.I input image format is **AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P**, but output video frame like follow.
I tried **libx264** and all work **correctly**.
Do you guys know what happen?Why encoded frame like that?

[image]

[image]

**My test code:**
https://github.com/BeiKeJieDeLiuLangMao/videotoolbox

**Resolution**
Data should align to 32.

Comment: Resolution on the image is strange. Check whether that toolbox codec has certain limitations on sizes. Like, it may expect sizes are divisible by 8 or something.

Comment: @the kamilz Image what i feed to toolbox codec is 478 * 850, divisible by 2 is ok for libx264. I try to feed 478 * 850 video to ffmpeg-cli toolbox codec, it works. And there isn't any option to set size or something related in AVOptions of toolbox.

Comment: I wonder what will happen if you supply 850x478 video. Worth trying..

Comment: @thekamilz If i feed 850 * 480 image to ffmpeg native lib, output frame like above.

Comment: @thekamilz I think maybe you are right.This issue maybe come with size problem.If codec handle this image as 300 * 850, it treat （400, 0）pixel as (100, 1), and output frame will like above.But i don't know why this happened, i set width and height (478 * 850) to AVCodecContext like what i do with libx264.

Comment: Also check any orientation settings, like aspect ratio.

Comment: I tried, but nothing changed.

Comment: I push my test code to github, would you mind to take a look?

Comment: Data should align to 32, that solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry I just noticed, busy day.. Anyway, so you solved the issue?

Comment: Yep, h264_videotoolbox expect data align to 32.